# JPA won't set default value to boolean column in Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to add a new column to a table with the default value "false".

I tried

```
private boolean fo_create = false;

@Builder.Default
private Boolean fo_created = Boolean.false;

@Column(columnDefinition = "boolean default false")
private boolean fo_created = false;
```

But none of those work. With the "Boolean" type, the column is created but remains null. With the boolean type, JPA throws an error and telling that it can't set the boolean to null ( although I specified the default value to false )

Can somebody help me solve this ?

Comment: If the value in the database can be null you must use Boolean. How do you crate the table?

Answer (score 0):

Entity class code

```
package com.example.demo.Entity;

import java.math.BigInteger;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Data;

/**
 * @author Sathiyaraj Ramamurthy 16 Nov 2021 5:47:26 AM
 *
 */
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "event")
public class EventDemo {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "event_name")
    private String eventName;
    @Column(name = "status", columnDefinition="tinyint(1) default 1")
    private boolean status;
}
```

Postman request Details
[image]

I'm using MySQL database. I believe it would be worked in Postgres as well